# Create Dynamic Arrays for Matrices named after loop iterator

Tags: c++

I have learnt a program to create number of arrays according to the user input. But now I want the situation for creating arrays for matrices (2D) to save the elements of the matrices.

User should enter the number of matrices he want and the size of each individual matrix and enter the respective numbers.

Here is the normal code which I studied. I want it to be usable for matrices.

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    unsigned int n;
    std::cout << "Enter number of arrays: ";
    std::cin >> n;
    double** array = new double*[n];
    unsigned int* sizeOfInnerArrays = new unsigned int[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter size of array " << i << ": ";
        std::cin >> sizeOfInnerArrays[i];
        array[i] = new double[sizeOfInnerArrays[i]];
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfInnerArrays[i]; ++j)
        {
            int element;
            std::cout << "Enter element " << j << " of array " << i << ": ";
            std::cin >> element;
            array[i][j] = element;
        }
    }

    //prints out each array as curly-brace enclosed sets of doubles
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "{";
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeOfInnerArrays[i] - 1; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << array[i][j] << ", ";
        }
        std::cout << array[i][sizeOfInnerArrays[i] - 1] << "}" << std::endl;
    }

    // free dynamically allocated memory
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        delete [] array[i];
    }
    delete[] array;
    delete[] sizeOfInnerArrays;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<int>>>` would reduce this to just a few lines of code and would be more safe.  Note that the major flaw with your code using `new[]` is that if `new[]` throws an exception in the middle of all of that creation logic, how do you "roll back" by calling `delete[]`?

Answer (score 0):

First, PaulMckenzie is right in their comment, you should really be using std::vector instead of directly using heap pointers, it is much simpler.

Also I didn't really know what you problem was, so here are some comments.

How is this a matrix if each row can have a different number of elements? That's is just a conceptual thing for me, as of now it is just a list of lists. If that is what you wanted cool, but if you wanted a matrix you need to be stricter on the dimensions.

There isn't anything objectively wrong with the code, I would say that this question really doesn't belong here. There isn't a problem with the code, and if there is please be explicit in saying what the problem is.

EDIT: I see you wanted to adapt it for a matrix, really I would say if you want practice just make a matrix class using std::vector

EDIT: What I meant about create a matrix class is literally that. Define a matrix class type that will handle all the generic operations of matrix of given dimensons, then your main does need all those for loops and iteration for creating the matrix. You would just store them with
`std::vector<Matrix> matricies; matricies.push_back(Matrix(2,3))`

Here is a reference for C++ classes http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/

Comment: Basically I need a program to define (create)  the number of matrices based on the user input and store the elements in it.

Comment: Like user should enter that he wants to create four matrices and then the matrices according to user input should be created. Then user stores the elements in the created matrices